# Color: rgba() workaround for Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, rgba

I've been able to successfully use the following workaround method:

```
background: rgb(42,42,42);
background: rgba(42,42,42,0.7);
```

However, this only works with `background:`, and doesn't work with `color:`.
Does anyone know a workaround to get it to work with `color:` ?

Comment: To be honest I just solved my own question:
`<!--[if lte IE 8]>
   <style type="text/css">
   a#scrollUp { color: #ffffff !important; } 
    </style>
<![endif]-->`
As for @Loktar, I don't think you read my question properly.
What's the appropriate thing to do now? Remove this question?

Comment: That's strange. Why would it work for one property but not another? Anyway if you'd like, you can post your workaround as an answer below, then mark it accepted when time permits (unless someone else has a better answer).

Comment: lol @CookieMonster I read it, was a weak attempt at humor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer only accepts percentages as RGB values. This will work

```
color: rgb(16%,16%,16%);
color: rgba(42,42,42,0.7);
```

**Microsoft Spec:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530749.aspx

**DEMO:** http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7082955.htm

**UPDATE** because of a bug in IE compatibility mode, if you declare two of the same thing, it ignores them both, the following will work in both compatibility mode and standards mode

```
h1 {
    color: rgb(16%,16%,16%);
}
h1 {
    color: rgba(42,42,42,0.7);
}
```

Comment: That's a way better workaround than the one I found myself! Thanks!


**Edit:** Wait.. this still doesnt work in IE <= 8, exactly the browser I had to find a workaround for... (It shows as black text)

Comment: I'm installing a virtual machine and will test this out myself, it should've worked, but there must be something else. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: So, I tested my demo link I provided, and it seems to be working. I changed the values to red to make it more noticeable as 16% of all colors is pretty darn close to black. The demo should now show red.

Comment: What you're seeing is a bug with compatibility view in IE. This updated example will work in both modes of IE. `h1 { color: rgb(100%,0%,0%); } h1 { color: rgba(0,255,0,0.5); }`

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research I found that this did the trick:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        a#scrollUp { 
            color: #ffffff !important; 
        }    
    </style> 
<![endif]-->
```

It uses conditional stylesheets; `lte IE 8` will match any IE version lower than or equal to 8. Just enter the proper (hex notation) color and prioritize it using `important` will work.

I hope this helps some other webdesigners as well!

I'm not sure about accepting my own answer, I just hope someone will still post a better (more efficient), working workaround.